# Why does this UPDATE prepared statement doesn't work, but works when used in SQL db

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, bindparam

I have the following statement:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE accounts SET loggedin = ? WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,lastcheck, NOW()) >= ? AND loggedin = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('iii', 0, 61, 0);
```

And it gives `500 internal server error`. When I tried the same on phpmyadmin running the sql thing like this:

```
UPDATE accounts SET loggedin = 0 WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,lastcheck, NOW()) >= 61 AND loggedin = 1
```

Worked without any problems.

Where is my problem?

Here's my error:

> PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference

Comment: Look in your error logs, what's the error message?

Comment: I'm on a shared hosting and I can't find the log. Give me 1 minute so I contact the support. aaaaaaaaaand support is offline for today

Comment: Why do you bind four parameters? You only have preparation for three...

Comment: Hello, it's only three ('iii', 0, 61, 0) the ('iii') is to declare that those 3 are ints

Comment: It should not make a difference, but you're preparing `0,61,0` but running the equivalent of `0,61,1` via phpmyadmin. ...but "500 internal server error" is an http error, not a MySQL one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bind_param` doesn't take values, it only takes parameters. You need to use variables. Something like:

```
$stmt->bind_param('iii', $s, $ss, $sss); 
$s = 0;
$ss= 61;
$sss = 0;
```

should resolve it.

Comment: Thank you!, this fixed the problem.